# What is the difference between mounting a File System and mounting a disk drive

Tags: c++, filesystems

i'm writing some programs to simulate a file system. I was just wondering what the differences are between mounting a file system and mounting a disk drive. What does it mean to mount a file system as well as mount a disk drive. What happens when I mount a file system rather than a disk drive?

Comment: What does "mounting a disk drive" mean? Only filesystems are mounted.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: drives are mounted too. That is the process that assigns a letter/link to the drive within the OS so its content can then be accessed, such as for subsequently mounting its file system.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Must be a Windows thing. Everyone else uses device files for that.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Well I've heard the term thrown out before. Must be using a file system analogy to refer to how drives need to be connect to the os first.

Answer (score 2):

You are talking apples and oranges here.  A disk drive is just a storage medium.  A file system is a way to organize data.  So you have to mount a drive before you can access its stored data, and mount the file system before you can access the data's hierarchy.  And then there are virtual disks and file system images to take into account, so you can mount a virtual drive without physical hardware, and mount a file system from an ISO or VM without storing it on its own dedicated drive.

Comment: Yes, I know, but this is just in terms of a simple system of constructing. It's not suppose to align completely with the real world. The real version would have the complexities like you mentioned. All I want is a simple answer, with a bit of insight or knowledge.